Redirect/pipe (or not) via a variable?
I'd like to be able to redirect a command, or not, by setting a variable - this is my attempt that doesn't work, does anyone know why/how I can get it to?
# REDIRECT is not set - this works fine
$ echo hi ${REDIRECT}
hi

# If I set this, I want to redirect to tmp...
$ REDIRECT="> /tmp/tmp"

# ...but this passes it as an argument to echo
$ echo hi ${REDIRECT}
hi > /tmp/tmp

I can't just set REDIRECT to the filename as sometimes I don't want to redirect at all, and later I'll possibly want to pipe (e.g. REDIRECT="| tee -a ...").
Anyone know how I can get bash to interpret the values as redirects, not arguments?

You could redirect to a variable target > "$target", which could just point to /dev/stdout, if needed.

@pmf that can be a temporary work-around, but what if I later want to pipe instead?

Piping and redirecting are completely different tasks (one goes to a process, the other one into a file), so combining them makes little sense. For this generality, use a function (not a variable), that operates on condition (using if or case). The function cen very well be parametrized to fit your specific needs.

It sounds like an XY problem.  Rather than trying to redirect based on a variable, just do the redirect when you otherwise would have set the variable.    In other words, instead of:
# BROKEN
if want_to_redirect; then
    REDIRECT="> /tmp/tmp"
fi
echo hi $REDIRECT   # DOES NOT WORK

You can do:
exec 3>&1
if want_to_redirect
    exec > /tmp/tmp
fi
echo hi

# If you want output of further commands to go back
# to the original output stream:
exec >&3

In the above want_to_redirect is some command that perhaps checks the environment or in some way decides whether or not you want to redirect; it's not really important what it is.  The point is: redirect the output of the shell, since all the commands that the shell executes will inherit its output streams.

Variables hold data. Functions hold code. Don't put code inside variables!.
If you want code that can pipe or redirect a string, write a function to implement that code then call that function:
prt() { printf '%s\n' "$@" > /tmp/tmp; }

prt hi


prt() { printf '%s\n' "$@" | tee -a ...; }

prt hi

or:
redirect() { cat > /tmp/tmp; }

echo hi | redirect


redirect() { tee -a ...; }

echo hi | redirect



Redirect/pipe (or not) via a variable?

Redirect always. Just redirect to stdout when not redirecting.
redirect=1
echo hi >&$redirect
exec {redirect}>/tmp/tmp
echo hi >&$redirect

You can read about file descriptors at wikipedia. See redirections bash documentation 2nd paragraph https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections .
It is sometimes typical to redirect stdout to stdout and a file using a process substitution:
exec 1> >(tee /tmp/tmp)


You can use a default value
prt() {
  local -r out=${1:-/dev/tty}
  printf '%s\n' "Hello World" > $out
}

and then
prt
prt /tmp/file

